# What is the purpose of the "@@INIT" action in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Just noticed that it is always the first action dispatched when a page is opened. Is it used to initialize the store with the default state from the reducer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this will answer your question.

> ```
> // When a store is created, an "INIT" action is dispatched so that every
> // reducer returns their initial state. This effectively populates
> // the initial state tree.
>
> dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.INIT })
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/55f1d08000b1b064eaa933bbbd132230e53bcccb/src/createStore.js#L242)

**UPDATE 24.02.2020**

Since @IsaacLyman explicitly [asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305492/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-init-action-in-react-redux/41305684#comment99561454_41305684) and got some upvotes on the comment, I decided to do an update in order to resolve the issue. To clarify, the source code in question is the following:

```
const ActionTypes = {
  INIT: `@@redux/INIT${/* #__PURE__ */ randomString()}`,
  ...
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/actionTypes.ts#L16)

The "randomString" was first introduced with [v4.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.1), in the [following commit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/commit/e6f6c7da7b39ed46273d05d150cf1f578973ac3c) you can see the actual changes (and read a short comment from the author what it is about). Nevertheless, I also found an "official statement" from Dan Abramov [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/186), which states:

> *"...any actions prefixed with `@@` are not meant to be handled. For example, you should never try to handle `@@INIT`. We might enforce that by slightly randomizing names (e.g. `@@INIT_2hj3jh34`).*
>
> *Handling `@@INIT` manually will break hot reloading. It is invoked at every hot reload, so if you do your initial data transformation there, it won't work the second time."*

Therefore, it is actually not intended for the random string to be visible.

Comment: In the redux source, `ActionTypes.INIT` refers to `"@@redux/INIT"` plus a random string. But in my web app the action type comes through as `"@@INIT"`, even though that particular string occurs nowhere in the redux source. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: @IsaacLyman Even though you asked quite some time ago, I updated my answer, in order to address the question in your comment.