# Set the counter state to Type : INIT

Tags: react-redux

I was working on simple counter app using redux.

Initial functions + and - are working fine.

Just wanted to add functionality of counter to stay 0 not to come in any negative value.

I added the condition but in redux console i saw type is changing , i want to add a conditon

if ( counter == 0 )
{
type : 'init'
}

but facing issue , can anyone help

Comment: Can you please provide your current reducer code and actions, as well as the full code for what you have tried.

It will also help if you can describe in more detail what your are seeing and how it differs from what you expect and what you want to see.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by 'i saw type is changing' and if you are trying to dispatch the `init` action as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305492/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-init-action-in-react-redux/41305684#comment99561454_41305684